# How to Pass Authtoken while loading Image using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

My code is

```
self.imgProfile.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "imageURL"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "ic_UserDefault"))
```

I am using default image lazy loading function to laod image.

Pods: pod 'SDWebImage' (Objective C)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the value of your token in the httpHeader in the request `SDWebImageDownloader` shared instance have a method to do that

**Swift implementation**

```
SDWebImageDownloader.shared()?.setValue(value: String!, forHTTPHeaderField: String!)
```

**Objective C example**

```
[[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] setValue:"Value" forHTTPHeaderField:"Token"];
```

After your login you should configure the `SDWebImageDownloader` passing your received AuthToken

Comment: In objective c file where we have to create instance? and i am not able to use swift code in my controller. Can you please explain me some more details.

Comment: @HirenRathod you don't need to create instance, only using the shared instance singleton provided by the library should work fine, only use the Objective C code that I put in the answer after your login process passing replacing "Value" for your Auth token and "Token" for your api token name